# How can I wrap flexbox children so that multiple children are stacked next to another child?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a table-like layout using flexbox:

```
+--------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
|      1       |       2       |        3        |       4       |
|              |               |                 |               |
+--------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

As the page gets smaller, I'd like to wrap the content to end up with something like this:

```
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|              |                        2                        |
|              |                                                 |
|              +-------------------------------------------------+
|      1       |                        3                        |
|              |                                                 |
|              +-------------------------------------------------+
|              |                        4                        |
|              |                                                 |
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried to use `flex-wrap: wrap` and extend the width of the trailing children to force them to wrap, but that just produces something like:

```
+-----------+--------------------------------------+
|           |                   2                  |
|           |                                      |
|     1     +--------------------------------------+
|           |
|           |
+-----------+--------------------------------------+
|                        3                         |
|                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                        4                         |
|                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

This is my current attempt:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.controls {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  max-width: 25%;  
}

.name, .artist, .album {
  flex: 0 0 75%;
  max-width: 75%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {  
  .name, .artist, .album {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="controls">PLAY</div>
  <div class="name">NAME</div>
  <div class="artist">ARTIST</div>
  <div class="album">ALBUM</div>
</div>
```

([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d8h50x9j/))

I'd prefer a pure CSS solution that works in IE11+.

Comment: Can't you wrap the last 3 inner divs into another div?

Comment: @Pangloss wouldn't that cause issues for those 3 divs when I don't want them to be stacked? Can I set flex properties for elements that aren't the immediate child of a `display: flex` ?

Comment: You can only apply flex properties to the children of a flex container. Any descendants beyond the children are not flex items, and flex properties don't apply. Of course, you can always apply `display: flex` to flex items, enabling flex properties deep into the tree structure.

Comment: I think it should be all fine, see this [updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tvgc6nh8/), hope that helps, in fact @Michael_B has already suggested an answer with a similar approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a nested flex container that switches items 2, 3 and 4 to a column on smaller screens.

Here's an example based on your code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="controls">PLAY</div>
    <div class="inner-container"><!-- nested flex container -->
        <div class="name">NAME</div>
        <div class="artist">ARTIST</div>
        <div class="album">ALBUM</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.inner-container {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 75%;
}

.controls {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
}

.name,
.artist,
.album {
    flex: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
     .inner-container { flex-direction: column; }
     .controls { align-self: center; }
}
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/d8h50x9j/6/)

Comment: Side note, Op uses @media min-width so wouldn't it be better to keep that?

Comment: @Pangloss, my code simply illustrates a concept. As OP is saying he wants stacked layout for smaller screens, `max-width` is simple and easy. But whether `min-width` or `max-width`, the overall concept remains the same.

Comment: Yep I get that, it was just a minor suggestion.